# CopyFileEx vs System.IO.File.Copy()

Tags: c#, copy

Currently having an odd scenario.

I manage a C# application to copy files from a server to a user's USB/SD Card.

I recently switched from System.IO.File.Copy(), to use a Pinvoke of CopyFileEx() that is in the kernal32.

I'm not here to request code, my current wrapper and code works fine (except this case).

I did find out that the original file's attributes were not being copied, but i have resolved that.

CopyFileEx copies the files fine, but there are a few Siemens PLC SD cards that are not functioning as expected. They appear to program fine, but the PLC never enters the run state. Oddly enough, a simple copy and paste from the file explorer works without any issues.

Does anyone know if CopyFileEx changes the encoding of a file or the encryption possibly?

I compared the binary of the files before and after the copy process, and the files are identical. So, I am currently stumped.

The only copy flag I am currently using is COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE, to get the status of the copy. (Mainly necessary for larger files.)

Anyone have a similar experience?

Thanks,

-J

Answer (score 1):

So it took a bit of digging and trial and error, but i figured out what was occurring.

The Copy functions are both fine.
My earlier assumptions about the encoding and encryption were wrong, and the problem was more related to the files/folders on the Siemen's SD card.

Turned out that even though all of the files were copied correctly, there was an empty folder that was not being copied from the server to the SD card, which kept the PLC from programming properly.

-J